# Kotlin plus() not changing the original List

Tags: android, kotlin, pojo

**TL,DR**

I have a Kotlin code where elements are added to arraylist but the list is not storing the new value although the return for the function shows the changed list.

```
Example problem: 
/* someList = ["A", "ab"] */
val x = someList.plus("Abc")

Example output: 
someList = ["A", "ab"] , x = ["A", "ab", "Abc"]
```

**Full Problem**

My code:

```
class FriendClass{
   /* others */
   @JsonProperty("messages")
   var messages: List<String>? = ArrayList()
}
```

```
class DataClass{
   /* singleton */
   /* others */
   @JsonProperty("friend_detail_list")
   var friendDetailList: List<FriendClass> = ArrayList()
}
```

```
class Adapter{
    val a = DataClass.getInstance().friendDetailList[0].messages?.plusElement("Hello")
    val b = DataClass.getInstance().friendDetailList[0].messages    
    val c = DataClass.getInstance().friendDetailList[0].messages?.toMutableList().add("Hello")
    val d = DataClass.getInstance().friendDetailList[0].messages 
    /* printing a, b, c, d */
}
```

My output:

`messages` already had ["a", "bcd", "xfd"] 
Now after printing the results are:

```
a = ["a", "bcd", "xfd", "Hello"]
b = ["a", "bcd", "xfd"] 
a = true
b = ["a", "bcd", "xfd"]
```

**How dow I make the original `messages` update it's values in the `FriendClass`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the signature of the function:

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.plusElement(element: T): List<T> {
    return plus(element)
}

/**
 * Returns a list containing all elements of the original collection and then the given [element].
 */
public operator fun <T> Collection<T>.plus(element: T): List<T> {
    val result = ArrayList<T>(size + 1)
    result.addAll(this)
    result.add(element)
    return result
}
```

It's clear from this that it doesn't modify the original list. What you want instead is probably:

```
val messages = DataClass.getInstance().friendDetailList[0].messages
DataClass.getInstance().friendDetailList[0].messages = messages.plusElement("Hello")
```

This will work because `messages` is mutable (declared with `var`).

There's a great article about some of these gotchas [here](https://craigrussell.io/2019/03/shooting-yourself-in-the-foot-while-adding-an-element-to-a-kotlin-list/).

Comment: I've updated my answer. Because you declare the list `messages` as a `List` you can't really modify it in place - but you can reassign its value to a different list.

Comment: I don't want to reassign, I want to update the original list, but I'll try your answer and reply soon

Comment: You can't as it stands. If you declare `messages` as an `ArrayList` or a `MutableList`, then you can just call `DataClass.getInstance().friendDetailList[0].messages?.add("Hello")`.